# Is there a PHP function or variable giving the local host name?

Tags: php, hostname

When a script runs under Apache, I insert `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` value into an error reporting e-mail message.

However, if a Web script forks a "worker" job with `nohup php ...`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` appears to be empty there. Thus, if an error occurs, it's reported without a host name.

Can I reliably get the host name by means of PHP, without calling Unix `hostname` command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[php_uname("n")](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5)
>   php_uname — Returns information about the
>   operating system PHP is running on
>
> php_uname() returns a description of the operating system PHP is
>   running on. This is the same string you see at the very top of the
>   phpinfo() output. For the name of just the operating system, consider
>   using the PHP_OS constant, but keep in mind this constant will contain
>   the operating system PHP was built on.
>
> On some older UNIX platforms, it may not be able to determine the
>   current OS information in which case it will revert to displaying the
>   OS PHP was built on. This will only happen if your uname() library
>   call either doesn't exist or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For [PHP >= 5.3.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php):

`$hostname = gethostname();`

For [PHP < 5.3.0 but >= 4.2.0 use this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php):

`$hostname = php_uname('n');`

For PHP < 4.2.0 you can try one of these:

```
$hostname = getenv('HOSTNAME'); 
$hostname = trim(`hostname`); 
$hostname = preg_replace('#^\w+\s+(\w+).*$#', '$1', exec('uname -a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_GLOBALS['MACHINENAME']` to obtain the information straight from the `globals` `array`.