# How fast is php_uname()?

Tags: php, optimization, uname

How fast is [php_uname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) say doing `php_uname('s n')` or `php_uname('a')`. The reason I ask is because I'd like to use it to determine which server I'm on and therefore the configuration (paths, etc).

This is related to [Is there a PHP function or variable giving the local host name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211885/is-there-a-php-function-or-variable-giving-the-local-host-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this:

```
<?php
  $tstart = microtime(true);

  php_uname('a');

  print 'it took '. sprintf("%f",microtime(true) - $tstart) ." seconds\n";
?>
```

And it produced this:

```
it took 0.000016 seconds
```

That is on a Core2Duo 2.4GHz Debian box.

I know it is an empirical test and all but I think that it shows that it will be fast enough for you.

I did not expect it to take a long time since uname only needs to make a very simple call to the kernel.

Comment: I don't know. The user's never gonna get that 0.000016 seconds back.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Comment: Just if anyone stops by here for the same question... this does not work if you're running PHP independently of a web server, e.g. in a cronjob.